# Why is a published research blocked from asking questions?

Tags: support

I an entrepreneur and scientist. Why am I blocked from getting basic information from a community website?

Answer (score 3):

The system automatically question-blocks users when they've repeatedly posted low quality -- as measured in (down-)votes -- questions.

Comment: ... which is also mentioned in the first sentence of the answer to the previous OP's question.

Comment: @Dmitry Good point, thanks. Closing as duplicate.